# Custom document metadata when using DocuSign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way that I can provide any custom document metadata when adding documents to my DocuSign envelopes when using the REST API?

DocuSign appear to enforce the use of a positive integer for the DocumentId's we provide in the envelope. Whilst we are indeed using a positive integer, sometimes, there is some additional info that we need to supply, which we would like to come back in the DocuSign webhook events for specific documents.

I've had a look at the Document object but can't see anything obvious that I could use. An example would be simply providing a true/false along with a specific document, which I can inspect when I receive the DS webhook events.

At the moment, the only workaround I can think of is to add an Envelope Custom Field which contains any of my DocumentId's where 'true' is applicable, which feels like a bit of a shoddy solution, and I don't know if there's a character limit in those Envelope Custom Fields, which could break such a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Custom envelope text fields give you complete flexibility on providing meta-data that you can get back from the webhook. Here is some information about this:

This is how you create a custom field for an envelope:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields/create/

This article shows code examples in 7 languagues on how to get the custom fields values :
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-custom-field-values/

Comment: Unfortunately this approach is not feasible as you’re limited to just 3 custom envelope fields, and if I were to utilise just one field with the affected documentids as comma separated values, there is a value limit of 100 chars, so this won’t work.

Comment: I'm not aware of a limit of 3 custom fields, where did you see this?

Comment: I'm seeing lots of examples for Envelope Custom Fields, but nothing for Document Custom Fields.  I'm sending out multiple documents in a single Envelope and would like to attach metadata to each one separately. I think I'm successful in creating the Document fields, but nothing is being returned in the Connect notifications. Is there an example for doing this? I tried Envelope fields as described in a "From The Trenches" article, but I'm running into the 100 character limit.  Thanks! randy

Comment: Here's the article mentioned just above: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-track-your-templates-envelope-custom-fields